# Repeat the Custom Content in Voice using IVR type flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am using twilio to make the calls.I am using ASP.NET MVC to create the response and gather inputs

Q1: How can i specify the attributes like lang, voice, loop, pause attributes for  verb

```
 public ActionResult Welcome(string msg) {
  var response = new TwilioResponse();
  response.Say("This is a Sample Message");
  return TwiML(response);
 }
```

Q2: I am using Gather input for options like 
         a)press 1 to repeat the message.
         b)press 2 to confirm.
         c)press 3 to repeat the menu options
     I am not able to find a way to forward my message parameter (**msg**) to the Gather  action.

```
 public ActionResult WelcomeCall(string msg)      
 {
     var response = new TwilioResponse();
     response.BeginGather(new
        {
            action = "http://testurl.azurewebsites.net/Gather",
            Digits = "1"
        });
     response.Say(msg);
     response.Say("To repeat the message, press one");
     response.Say("To confirm, press two");
     response.Say("To repeat the menu options, press three");
     response.EndGather();
     return TwiML(response);
  }

  public ActionResult Gather(string Digits) 
  {
      var response = new TwilioResponse();
      if(Digits==1) 
      {
         response.Say(msg);
      }
      return TwiML(response);
   }
```

Could you please provide a way to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

The `Say` method (and most of the TwiML methods) have a second parameter that takes an anonymous type allowing you to specify verb attributes:

```
response.Say("This is a Sample Message", new { voice="alice", loop="2" } );
```

To pass the message to the Gather handler, you could just append it to the action URL:

```
response.BeginGather(new
{
    action = "http://testurl.azurewebsites.net/Gather?msg=" + msg,
    Digits = "1"
});
response.EndGather();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.To pass the message to gather handler you said /Gather?msg="+msg  then in the public ActionResult Gather(string msg, string Digits) as parameters.Please confirm.I am not able to receive the msg data in Gather Action

Comment: when i am passing like above.I am getting "we are sorry an application error occurred" or "Gather End" error is occurring.Could you help me on solving this issue.